# Relative Positioning an Element add Horizontal Scroll Bar to Web Page

Tags: html, css

When I am trying to set the relative position of  "ul" element nested under 
div  with id nav , it is adding Horizontal Scroll Bar on Web Page. Please help 
to understand the reason for this & solution for this. Basically I want to bring the Navigation menu in centre of screen.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>TESTING PAGE</title>

  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    #nav {
      background-color: black;
      color: white;
    }
    
    #nav ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      position: relative;
      left: 100px;
    }
    
    #nav ul li {
      display: inline;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <h1>NAVIGATION BAR</h1>

  <div id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li>HOME</li>
      <li>ABOUT</li>
      <li>CONTACT</li>

    </ul>

  </div>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Position relative and left 100px causes it. Take a look at this navigation for an ideas: https://css-tricks.com/flexbox-bar-navigation/

Comment: you could just use margin-left instead of relative positioning or ist that not an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it overflows is because if you do not explicitly apply a value for the `display` property of `ul`, the value defaults to `block`.

Elements with `display: block;` take up 100% width, so, since you move the element `100px` to the right, `#nav ul` will overflow the document by `100px`.

You can test this by applying a border to `ul` and then try changing its `display` property to, say, `inline` for example.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#nav {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

#nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  left: 100px;

  border: solid red 1px;
  /* try un-commenting this and see what happens!
  display: inline;
  */
}

#nav ul li {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<h1>NAVIGATION BAR</h1>
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li>HOME</li>
    <li>ABOUT</li>
    <li>CONTACT</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And if you would like to move the `ul` element to the center of `#nav`, then simply add `left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);` to `#nav ul`.

Transform Translate positions an element relative to itself, so, if an element's width is 100px and you apply that specific transform, it will reposition that element 50px  (half of its own width) to the left of its current left position.

It should be noted that you should also apply a `padding-left: 0` to `#nav ul` since `ul` elements by default have padding applied to them.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#nav {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

#nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;

  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  border: solid red 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto; /* to remove the default top & bottom margins for inline-blocks */
  padding-left: 0; /* to remove the default padding-left for ULs */
}

#nav ul li {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<h1>NAVIGATION BAR</h1>
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li>HOME</li>
    <li>ABOUT</li>
    <li>CONTACT</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @Ishaan NP, my friend. Glad I could help. An up vote would be appreciated :D

Comment: Hi Anthony, i tried an up vote for your solution. but  still due to less reputation score of me, my upvotes are not displayed publicly.

Comment: @Ishaan ty sir i appreciate the thought nonetheless

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution to your problem:

```css
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    #nav {
      background-color: black;
      color: white;
    }
    
   li {
      display: inline;
    }
    
    ul{
      padding-left: 0px;
      display: wrap;
      text-align: center;  
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>TESTING PAGE</title>

</head>

<body>

  <h1>NAVIGATION BAR</h1>

  <div id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li>HOME</li>
      <li>ABOUT</li>
      <li>CONTACT</li>

    </ul>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Use `display: wrap;` property for the `ul` along with `text-align: center;`. This way they get aligned to the center without the need to add additional hard coded `left: 100px;` which is added in your code.

Comment: Care to explain the reason for downvote? Did the answer not solve the question?

Comment: he also asked for help to understand WHY it's happening, not just for a solution. plus, the solution you offered is unnecessarily "hacky" so to speak. your solution also contains code for the `h1` element which wasn't requested. AND lastly the `ul` still appears off center since you haven't dealt with its padding

Comment: Thanks Alok for your solution. It was also good. But Anthony's answer was more relevant to my query. So  I had marked his answer as right. It marked a downvote for your solution by itself.

Comment: Well if the answer helped you can upvote it, and sure , happy to be of any help.